# Rspec - Test that rails view renders a specific partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails 3.2.13 app running rspec-rails 2.14.0 and am trying to confirm that a view renders a particular partial in my test. It actually *does* work, but I need to add this test. Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'users/items/index.html.haml' do
  let(:current_user) { mock_model(User) }

  context 'when there are no items for this user' do
    items = nil

    it 'should render empty inventory partial' do
      response.should render_template(:partial => "_empty_inventory")
    end

  end
end
```

This runs without error, but does not pass. The failure is:

```
Failure/Error: response.should render_template(:partial => "_empty_inventory")
   expecting partial <"_empty_inventory"> but action rendered <[]>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

**EDIT**

This works for me, but Peter's solution is better...

```
context 'when there are no items for this user' do

  before do
    view.stub(current_user: current_user)
    items = nil
    render
  end

  it 'should render empty inventory partial' do
    view.should render_template(:partial => "_empty_inventory")
  end

end
```

For some reason it was counter-intuitive to me to have to call `render` on a view, but there you go...

Comment: What type of spec is this?  It looks like it's a view spec, but there's no render call.  And it uses a 'response' object, which is indicative of a controller spec.

Comment: It is a view spec, you're right. I'm trying to piece code together from different code I've found. I didn't see anything obvious in the docs: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/view-specs/view-spec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the way one usually tests whether a particular partial is rendered in a view spec is by testing the actual content of the partial.  For example, assume that your _empty_inventory parial has the message 'There is no inventory'.  Then you might have a spec like:

```
  it "displays the empty inventory message" do
    render
    rendered.should_not have_content('There is no inventory')
  end
```

Alternately, you could use a controller spec, in which case you need to call the 'render_views' method when setting up the spec.  Then you can do something similar to

```
it 'should render empty inventory partial' do
  get :index, :user_id => user.id
  response.should render_template(:partial => "_empty_inventory")
end
```

Assuming you've set up the state for the contoller spec.

Comment: I think some of the problem is that I didn't want that logic in the controller, but perhaps it shouldn't be in the view.

Comment: In an rspec files, is there any way to render only a partial and then check if rendered content exists in a specific dom?